# NoSql self join like

Tags: mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, self-join, nosql

I want to understand if I can do the following thing with NoSql in any way.   I will take flights as example.

Lets say I have table or collection of flights with the following info:

```
...
{ from:XXX, to:YYY, date:01-01-2016 } 
{ from:YYY, to:XXX, date:02-02-2016 }
...
```

I need to be able to perform something like self join to find the full route :
`{from:XXX, to:YYY, outbound:01-01-2016, inbound:02-02-2016}`

the table should have a lot of `from` and `to` locations.

Is it possible to do it with no relational DB?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do it with no relational DB?

That's the wrong question to ask. The idea of NoSQL is to use *specialized* data stores for specific problems, instead of attempting to solve every problem with the same tool.

Your use case is unclear, however - depending on what data you use to query, you could simply do two queries and merge the result(s), or use a simple `$or` query (in mongodb) to query for paths back and forth. There's dozens of ways to solve this with all kinds of tools, but it depends on the *exact* problem you want to solve.

The example of flights is not even a good fit for RDBMSs, because this is usually a [routing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Routing_algorithms) where it might be allowed (or necessary) to combine two or more flights for each direction - neo4j might be the *simpler* tool for graph problems (note that I'm not saying 'better', because that can mean many things...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient way to do this in AWS DynamoDB.

Create a table with the following schema:

```
HashKey:  From_City-To_City
RangeKey: Time
```

So in your case your table would look like:

```
HashKey     RangeKey
XXX-YYY     01-01-2016
YYY-XXX     02-02-2016
```

Now given a flight from XXX to YYY on 01-01-2016, you can find the return flight by doing a DynamoDB query like this:

```
HashKey=="YYY-XXX" and RangeKey > "01-01-2016".
```

This query should be very efficient because the hash key "YYY-XXX" is already defined and range key is sorted/indexed. So you can have tons of flight info in your table, but your query execution time should stay (mostly) the same regardless of the growth in table size.